# Is it possible to store pathparams as a list?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a Rest Service that I want to respond to requests with the following paths

1) `/v1/config/type/service`

2) `/v1/config/type/service, service2`

What I'd like is to be able to store the path param `serviceName` as a `List` where each element is delimited by a comma. For example, if someone types `v1/config/foo/bar1,bar2,bar3` I'd like `serviceName` to be a `List` with 3 elements (bar1, bar2, bar3). Right now it just returns a list with 1 element that contains all three service strings. Is that even possible? Or is that something I'll simply have to parse. The code I have is shown below, it's pretty rough as I'm in the beginning stages of the project:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
@Path("/v1/config")
public class ServiceRetriever extends Application { 

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}

@GET
@Path("{type}/{serviceName}")
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response getServices(@PathParam("type") String type, @PathParam("serviceName")List<String> serviceNames, 
        @QueryParam("with_config") boolean withConfig, @QueryParam("with_drive") boolean withDriver) throws IOException
{
    //some random file i made to test that we can return a zip
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/dummy.zip");
    System.out.println(serviceNames.size()); //returns 1

    //we can change the zip file name to be whatever 
    return Response.ok(file).header("Content-Type","application/zip").
            header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file.getName()).build();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got this right.. but why not keep using 1 string as input and on the server side split it by `,`. to get the list of params?
maybe I didn't understand you too well..

Comment: @LiranBo yeah i realized it's worded poorly. Right now that's how I'm doing it. The last part of the path `bar1, bar2, bar3` I just store as a string and split on the comma. I didn't know if there was a fancier JAX-RS way to do without having to split

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you have to alter the deserialization process of that variable. Typically only query parameters are lists so this might not be compatible with some libraries.
You could:

- Capture the parameter as a string and parse it internally via helper method (obvious)
- Create your own annotation like @PathParamMutli and return `Arrays.asList(parameter.split(","));`. Ideally you should have access to the framework source code and branching privileges.
- Use a query parameter instead